# Crash testing with Javascript or python on Java

Tags: java, javascript, python

I need to 'crash test' a couple of Java applications with mainly Javascript.
By crash test I mean I need to pass the Java class or method all different types of random inputs until it crashed then record it. But I have ran into the problem that I don't know the most efficient way to call a certain Java class or method from Javascript.
Then I also do not know which scripting language would be better for the job, python or javascript. Both languages have to work offline and I don't know if I will have access to the command prompt / admin privileges to use the command line to call the classes or methods. So what do I do? 
2 Questions: 
How do I call Java classes and Methods in Javascript? 
Would python be better for this job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do I call Java classes and Methods in Javascript?

Java runs in JVM, Javascript runs in Javascript engine like v8. so first you need a layer which Java and Javascript can both run in. For now there are some ways to run Javascript in JVM, these ways all provide interoperability between Javascript and Java. you can Google 'Javascript JVM' to go ahead.

Would python be better for this job?

'better' depends on much. for programming language,  I like Javascript. Javascript and the libraries mainly designed for web development, Python is more like a common programming language. also Python cloud run in JVM with help of JPython

Comment: Thank you very much! I will have to think about whether to go ahead and use Javascript or CoffeeScript. But I didn't know that there were Javascript JVM's. Thanks